# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed, mat.hpp line 548

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

first I gave the following error in the code
int KK = 10;
int colors[KK];
then I wrote const int instead of kk and fixed the error

I'm using the opencv library but I'm getting an error somewhere. When i and j are 713 48, they do not give an error, but in the next cycle, i and j are 713 and 49, and they give an error code.(OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 548)

the error gives in this row.

clustered.at(i,j) = (float)(colors[bestLabels.at(1,z)]);

I share the detailed code below

int KK = 10;

```
int colors[KK];

Mat p;
Mat bestLabels, centers;
vector<Mat> bgr, bgrBN;
split(frame_color, bgr);
Mat mask, clustered;
Mat clusteredAll = Mat::zeros(frame_color.rows, frame_color.cols, CV_32F);
for (int k = 0; k < contoursN.size(); k++)
{
    mask = Mat::zeros(frame_color.rows, frame_color.cols, CV_8U);
    drawContours(mask, contoursN, k, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
    clustered = Mat::zeros(frame_color.rows, frame_color.cols, CV_32F);

    int A = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < frame_color.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < frame_color.cols; j++)
    if (mask.at<uchar>(i,j) != 0)
        A++;

    if (A > 20)
    {
        p = Mat::zeros(A, G, CV_32F);
        double moy = 0;
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < frame_color.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < frame_color.cols; j++)
            {
                if (mask.at<uchar>(i,j) != 0)
                {
                    p.at<float>(z,0) = bgr[0].data[i*frame_color.cols+j] / 255.0;
                    p.at<float>(z,1) = bgr[1].data[i*frame_color.cols+j] / 255.0;
                    p.at<float>(z,2) = bgr[2].data[i*frame_color.cols+j] / 255.0;
                    z++;
                    moy = moy + frame.at<uchar>(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
        moy = moy/z;
        double var = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < frame_color.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < frame_color.cols; j++)
        if (mask.at<uchar>(i,j) != 0)
        var = var+(frame.at<uchar>(i,j) - moy)*(frame.at<uchar>(i,j) - moy);
        var = var/(z*z);


        int K = 1 + log(1+(A/A0)+(var/var0));

        kmeans(p, K, bestLabels, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

        for(int i=0; i<KK; i++)
            colors[i] = 255/(i+1);

        z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < frame_color.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < frame_color.cols; j++)
            {
                if (mask.at<uchar>(i,j) != 0)
                {
                    clustered.at<float>(i,j) = (float)(colors[bestLabels.at<int>(1,z)]);
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
        clusteredAll = clusteredAll + clustered;
        clustered.convertTo(clustered, CV_8U);
    }
```

Comment: I have 2 suggestions at first glance:

1. You probably mean `bestLabels.at<int>(0, z)` at the erronous line.

2. `z++` should probably be moved outside the `if` statement checking for mask

Comment: yes the error about bestLabels.at<int>(1, z) I try this code int de = bestLabels.at<int>(1, 0); cout << "\n" << de; then the program run and don't give error but ı tried this code int den = bestLabels.at<int>(1, 1);
      cout << "\n" << de;  the program gave same error